# After the Installation of Ubuntu on my MacBookPro I can't restart the system only black screen, how to fix that?

Tags: 22.04, reboot, macbook-pro

After the installation of ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on my MacBookPro mid-2010 as the sole OS (it was running El Captian) via a bootable usb stick following the steps in the this link: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview. As a final step I was requested to restart the computer, after the auto restart ubuntu booted up (showing the ubuntu logo) then after loading for a few seconds showed a black screen with the mouse, after force shutting down and starting it again it booted up and showed the same black screen.

What is the problem and how can I solve it?